# Users getting linked unwanted to main mu in WordPress multisite (WPMU)

Tags: multisite, users, user-registration, user-access

Sometimes in WPMU a user from one of the networksites gets linked to the main mu as well. It seems to me like it is completely random and very rare so I cannot easily simulate this. It's easy to just delete the user from the main mu but what I am wondering why this is happening and how to fix it.

Has anyone around here had a similar experience ?

Comment: Login/Logout usually happens on the main site. Maybe they get redirected there?

Comment: Maybe you have some plugin that creates a registration form somewhere that some users stumble upon and register.